# How to post query data from a python file to a flask endroute?

Tags: python, flask, post, get

I am trying to post some query data that does some simple calculations based off of the users responses to the flashcard questions. I have those queries written in a stats.py file, and I want to retrieve them in the front end of my react.js application. My plan was to post the data to a flask end route and then use axios to get it in the front end. I have easily managed to post the users response data from the front end (react.js) to the flask end route with out any problems. The problem Im running into now is I don't know how to "trigger" the post request. When accessing the endpoint url in a browser, it performs a get request. When posting the user response data, the post request was triggered by whichever answer they clicked on or whenever they clicked submit. I found that part pretty easy to do in react.js but I'm not sure how to do it in python.
here is what my stats.py file looks like, this is where I want to post the query data from:

```
from typing import Any
from main import Db
import requests
import json

d = Db()

api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats'

def get_total_percent_correct(user_id):
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE guess = answer AND user_id = \'%s\'' % user_id)
    total = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user = \'%s\'' % user_id)
    return float(correct/total)

def get_percent_correct_for_flashcard(user_id,flashcard_id):
    total = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user = \'%s\' AND WHERE flashcard_id = \'%s\'' % (user_id, flashcard_id))
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.cards WHERE flashcard_id = \'%s\' AND WHERE guess = answer AND WHERE user_id = \'%s\'' % (flashcard_id, user_id))
    return float(correct/total)

def get_stats_for_flashcard(user_id, flashcard_id):
    attempts = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.responses WHERE user = \'%s\' AND WHERE flashcard_id = \'%s\'' % (user_id, flashcard_id))
    correct = d.db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards.cards WHERE flashcard_id = \'%s\' AND WHERE guess = answer AND WHERE user_id = \'%s\'' % (flashcard_id, user_id))
    missed = attempts - correct
    return (attempts, correct, missed)


def get_most_missed_flashcard(user_id):
    questions = d.db_query('SELECT DISTINCT(flashcard_id) FROM cards.responses WHERE user = \'%s\'' % user_id)
    holder = []
    for i in questions:
        holder.append(get_percent_correct_for_flashcard(user_id, i))
    return min(holder)

create_row_data = {'accuracy': get_total_percent_correct}
print(create_row_data)
r = requests.post(url=api_url, json=create_row_data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

and here is some code from my "main.py" file which contains the end route where I want to post the data to:

```
@app.route('/stats', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def request_data_stats():
  if request.method == 'GET':
        return make_response('Get Request')
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.get_json()
    userstats = data['accuracy']
    print(userstats)
    return userstats
```

I appreciate any help! thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem here. Your endpoint is okay. In your stats.py file you need to jsonify the value of accuracy key that you are sending otherwise Flask would throw error. Use `json.loads(get_total_percent_correct)` to create a string type value for accuracy key.

Comment: There's also this thing I don't understand. How do you intend to use this stats.py file and where? You are much better off integrating stats.py in your Flask app. Provide  GET and POST endpoints from Flask so that your frontend can query them and send responses to Flask, and then get accuracy as response from the sever.

Comment: I need the query data so I can display statistics for the user in the front end. I think I understand what you're saying. So in the front end I would call the  flask end point and just move the queries from the stats.py file to my main.py file in the end route so they run when it gets called? Sorry I'm new to backend, i appreciate your help

Comment: Yes. Javascript (JS) cannot load Python files. You can only make network calls from JS and do something with it. Yes, use stats.py file in your Flask app (remove that requests.post call code), and integrate that with views. // I'm new too. No problem. :) If you get stuck with Flask try its tutorial. It is pretty good. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/

Comment: okay thanks, I'm working on the project with someone else who is running the python and SQL part and they wrote that code in the stats.py file for me to use, and I never thought about moving it. thanks for the help!